# Handling special entities like & nbsp; , & pound; in HtmlCleaner

Tags: java, jsp, web-crawler, web-scraping

I am using HtmlCleaner library for html content extraction. It works fairly but with few limitations.

It is not able to handle special characters like &pound or quotes etc. For e.x.
for url : http://www.basicelegancefurnishings.co.uk/alaska-3-and-2-seater-sofa-setspan-classukmadespan-p-280.html, On giving xpath to price, It gives me "& pound;" inplace of £

Is there any property which we can set in htmlcleaner for handling this or any other solution.

Thanks

Jitendra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't believe HtmlCleaner can do this. However, you can use [Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) to "unescape" the html, like this:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&pound;679.00");
```

will produce `£679.00`.

Instead of HtmlCleaner, I would recommend you try [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: I didn't know about StringEscapeUtils. Thanks for it. Content Extraction in my case is based on xpaths. Does Jsoup support that ?

Comment: jsoup supports CSS selectors for content extraction; should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The version of htmlcleaner I am using is 2.2, and `org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties - setTransSpecialEntitiesToNCR(true)` is useful to me. While I have to use the `string.replace("&#160;", "&nbsp;")` to make the html content I got be right completely.

Answer (score -1):

This can now be done through org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties - setTransSpecialEntitiesToNCR(true).

Comment: "setTransSpecialEntitiesToNCR" parameter only affects serialization behavior - so your answer is incorrect, HtmlCleaner (still) does not handle this kind of unescaping HTML entities. See also http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/parameters.php