# java - handling &nbsp as a string

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

How can I replace the `&nbsp` charactes that I'm parsing from an HTML file with a " " ?
There are many questions and "accepted" answers regarding this like,

[How to remove &nbsp; with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137892/how-to-remove-nbsp-with-jsoup)

[How to remove "&nbsp;" from java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318404/how-to-remove-nbsp-from-java-string)

[Handling special entities like & nbsp; , & pound; in HtmlCleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315979/handling-special-entities-like-nbsp-pound-in-htmlcleaner)

but I'm still not getting through this by using all the solutions given in these links,

```
if(tr.text().replace("\u00a0", "").isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("testing---");
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?
Can jsoup be used in this scenario? I read that in one of the answers.

**UPDATE** 
This is the HTML part I am trying to get data from.

```
<TR>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boBL noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=xl27boL noWrap align=right>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: are you saying that the noWrop thingy is causing the problems?

Comment: No, actually, JSoup is really tolerant of invalid HTML -- that's one of the great things about it.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137892/how-to-remove-nbsp-with-jsoup) works correctly. The reason you're getting `false` for `isEmpty` is that the text of the `tr` elements doesn't consists **only** of `&nbsp;` characters — there are also other whitespace characters in there. You'll want to add a `trim` call:

```
if(tr.text().replace("\u00a0", "").trim().isEmpty()){
// Here --------------------------^^^^^^^
    System.out.println("testing---");
}
```

I figured this out simply by looking at the text returned by `tr.text()` when I ran your example HTML into JSoup; basic debugging.

Comment: hi Sir, it is still not working for me, i have two TR tags, in the first TR tag there is a &nbsp in the last TD and in the next TR tag i have all TD's with &nbsp. by adding trim() (which i already had tried before posting the question), only the last TD of the first TR got detected with & nbsp and not the next TR which had all &nbsp in its TD's. hope i was clear

Comment: Is jsoup Really required for this?  Won't a regular expression do it?

Comment: @VasanthNagKV: No idea what the problem is, then; I copied and pasted your HTML into a file, loaded that file with JSoup, ran the above, and got `true` for `isEmpty`. You'll have to step through with a debugger and figure out what it is. I'm 99.9% certain it has nothing to do with the `&nbsp;` thing. It's not difficult to find out, just inspect the string you get back from `tr.text()`.

Comment: System.out.println("the string is  "+ tr.text()) - this gives an empty line as an output :(

Comment: @VasanthNagKV: Don't use `System.out.println` for debugging, use a ***debugger*** for debugging. I expect there are probably spaces there, or other characters that aren't obvious when dumped to the console.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the document from Jsoup use StringEscapeUtils

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(test));
```

use this library org-apache-commons-lang.jar.

Answer (score 0):

For simpler solution you can use the existing

```
java.lang.string.trim();
```

You can implement it using

```
 WebUI.getText().trim();
```